# How to use await with traceur compiler on the fly?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-6, traceur

I'm needing help to configure my browser to work with trace compiler. I have tried of several ways to put a simple async code to work, but with no sucess yet. The code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1 id="message"></h1>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/bin/traceur.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/src/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="module">
    $traceurRuntime.options = traceur.util.Options.experimental();
    console.log("t", traceur, "tr", $traceurRuntime, "tro", $traceurRuntime.options); 
    function changeTest(text) {
        return new Promise().resolve(text+text);
    }

    async function run(text) {
        var newText = await encrypt(text);
    }

    console.log(run("asdf"));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The traceur compiler link show that it should work is [here](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#%2F%2F%20Options%3A%20--annotations%20--array-comprehension%20--async-functions%20--async-generators%20--exponentiation%20--export-from-extended%20--for-on%20--generator-comprehension%20--member-variables%20--proper-tail-calls%20--require%20--symbols%20--types%20%0Afunction%20changeTest(text)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise().resolve(text%2Btext)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20run(text)%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20newText%20%3D%20await%20encrypt(text)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(run(%22asdf%22))%3B).

The following error appears:

> ["file:///.../traceur_inline_script_1.js:8:8: Semi-colon expected",
>   "file:///.../traceur_inline_script_1.js:9:9: Semi-colon expected"]

The tracerRuntimeOptions looks ok:

```
Options {
    arrowFunctions: true,
    blockBinding: true,
    classes: true,
    computedPropertyNames: true,
    defaultParameters: true…
}
annotations: true
arrayComprehension: true
arrowFunctions: true
asyncFunctions: true
asyncGenerators: true
atscript: (...)
blockBinding: true
classes: true
commentCallback: false
computedPropertyNames: true
debug: false
debugNames: false
defaultParameters: true
destructuring: true
experimental: (...)
exponentiation: true
exportFromExtended: true
forOf: true
forOn: true
freeVariableChecker: false
generatorComprehension: true
generators: true
inputSourceMap: false
lowResolutionSourceMap: false
memberVariables: true
moduleName: "default"
modules: (...)
modules_: "bootstrap"
numericLiterals: true
outputLanguage: "es5"
parseOptions: Object
properTailCalls: true
propertyMethods: true
propertyNameShorthand: true
referrer: ""
require: true
restParameters: true
script: false
sourceMaps: (...)
sourceMaps_: false
sourceRoot: false
sourceRoot_: false
spread: true
symbols: true
templateLiterals: true
transformOptions: Object
typeAssertionModule: null
typeAssertions: false
types: true
unicodeEscapeSequences: true
unicodeExpressions: true
validate: false
__proto__: Options
```

I tried several variations but no sucess yet. Someone can help me to write a working code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd move on to Babel.

Comment: @torazaburo Interesting, thanks. I will git it a try. If you post a working solution with babel I'll embrace it. Thx.

Comment: Do you know a link to download the version for browsers? The doc says `A browser version of Babel is available from browser.js inside a babel-core npm release` but I didnt find it.

Comment: Any progress on this one ? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Yes I did. The truth I was misundestading how to use traceur transpiler. I solved the problem using something like grunt that compiles the file to me to es7 and then I use this compiled file on my html page. The await operator works fine. When I have some time I will explain better, but this is the direction.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> The truth I was misunderstanding how to use the Traceur transpiler. I solved the problem by using something like grunt to compile the file to ECMAScript-7, then used the compiled output in my HTML page. The await operator works fine. When I have some time I will explain better, but this is the direction.

**References**

- [Cross Stitching: Elegant Concurrency Patterns for JavaScript](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/cross-stitching-elegant-concurrency-patterns-for-javascript/)